# Is asking for code off-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I like glitches, but I really don’t know much about games and their code. If I’m asking about a glitch (e.g. an iron golem falling through the floor in MC Dungeons), can I ask for specific code that may have caused this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** (or: **no, you can't ask for specific code that may have caused a glitch.)**

'Code' indicates someone would have to dive into the programming of a game. Apart from this not being something we tend to do in general, I presume most - if not all - cases will be closed as off-topic for falling under Game Development.
Even asking why a glitch or bug (by their very nature being unintended) occurs at all would fall under that umbrella.

Comment: Do you know of any site that I could go o to find this stuff out?

Comment: @Diehe GameDev.SE or if you have code that needs fixing, StackOverflow. Beware: SO accepts only coding questions with code included.

Comment: No, it’s not my code that I’m wondering about.